# How to ffill() the rows in every nth column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table with 400+ columns and would like to 'ffill()' every third column based on the first value.

The data below is the result of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os


cwd = os.getcwd()

df = pd.read_excel( cwd + '/FILES/BH.xlsx' , skiprows=9)

df = df.drop(columns = ['Unnamed: 0', 'Unnamed: 1','Unnamed: 2','Unnamed: 3'])

df= df.T 

df[0] = df[0].ffill()

df= df.T 

print(df)
```

**My Table**

[image]

**My Expected Result**

this is my only problem. To 'ffill()' every third column based on the first value on Top

[image]

I've already checked some of samples here but most of them are hardcoded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command:

```
df[list(df.columns)[2::3]] = df[list(df.columns)[2::3]].iloc[0]
```

By the way, ffill() fill only missing/None values in the column. This is equivalent to fillna(method="ffill").

Comment: Thanks It WORKS!  but only with a glitch, it also counts the Index, the first column is there a way that we exclude the count the 1st row and noticed it doubled the output in columns

Comment: You can set the first column as the index of the dataframe using set_index("col_name") or change the slicing values in both side: list(df.columns)[3::3]

Comment: `df[list(df.columns)[3::3]] = df[list(df.columns)[3::3]].iloc[0]`. it's Good Now !.. Thanks a  alot!